# Two Update statements on a row are running simultaneously with no locking in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, concurrency, locking

I relied on row locking in mysql to prevent simultaneous running of one php script when working on one userid.

I used following

```sql
UPDATE users SET rowlock = 1 WHERE id = ? AND rowlock = 0
```

and then in php

```
if($stmt->affected_rows == 0)
```

Ideally, if one instance of php script updates the rowlock to 1 then the second instance will not be able to update.
second php script instance will have affected rows as 0 and it won't be possible to run same script twice on one userid.

However to my surprise if two scripts are ran at the same time then both are able to have affected rows as 1.

Comment: That can't happen if `id` is unique. Something else must be going on.

Comment: How do you know the second instance didn't run after the first one finished and unlocked the row?

Comment: Just naming your column `rowlock` does not have anything to do with row locking. Locks are released when the transaction finishes.